# Sampling and the Discrete Fourier Transform

Tags: fast-fourier-transform, fourier-transform

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$.  We'd like to take the Fourier Transform of this function, defined as
$$F(s) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-i \, 2\pi \, s \, x}dx.$$
However, a computer can't do this in general.  Instead, we "sample" the function and then compute the Discrete Fourier Transform.  Sampling is modeled as multiplication with a comb function $\text{III}(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\delta(x-n)$.

So we take the Fourier Transform of $f\,\text{III}$.

At this point I'm confused about a few things.

1)  Shouldn't we model sampling as multiplication with a comb and a rect function like this:  $f\,\text{III}\,\Pi_\Delta$ where 
$$\Pi_\Delta(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}1 & \text{ if } |x|/\Delta < 0.5\\0 & \text{otherwise}\end{array}\right..$$
Don't we need this in order to account for the fact that we have a finite number of samples?

2)  How does the Fourier Transform of $f\,\text{III}$ relate to the Discrete Fourier Transform of the samples?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use $Ш$ for Dirac comb.

Comment: @HenryW.  I would LOVE to!  I can't seem to edit your post and view the latex.  What's the latex for that symbol?

Comment: It is a Cyrillic letter by itself: Ш Related:http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124738/i-just-want-to-write-sha-without-ruining-everything